# Expected value of continuous random variable: a definition

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ we define the expected value of a random variable $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
\tag{1}
\mathbb{E}(X):=\int_{\Omega}X\,d\mathbb{P}.
$$

Suppose that $X$ is absolutely continuous with density $f_X$, i.e., $f_X$ satisfies
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(x)\,dx, \hspace{0.3cm} x\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Now we define the expected value of $X$ as
$$
\tag{2}
\mathbb{E}(X):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)\,dx.
$$

My question is the following.

> How does one derive definition $(2)$ from the general one - definition $(1)$?

I know that, upon considering $\text{id}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\int_{\Omega}(\text{id}\circ X)\,d\mathbb{P}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,d\mathbb{P}_X(x),
$$
where $\mathbb{P}_X$ is a probabilty on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ given with $\mathbb{P}_X(B):=\mathbb{P}(X\in B)$.
I also notice that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(x)\,dx=\mathbb{P}_X((-\infty,x]),
$$
which, in a very remote way, smells of $d\mathbb{P}_X=f_X$...

Obviously, non of this is formal and I am stuck. 
All suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Have a read about change of measure - radon nikodym derivative. Basically when you change the measure $d\mathbb{P}_X(x)$ to dx, you get the extra $f_X(x)$ term in the product.

Comment: You could check out https://books.google.com/books?id=e9saZ0YSi-AC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false.